# Text field problems Xcode

Tags: textfield, zstack

I’m creating an app and need to make a signup/login page. I added a background using a picture and a zstack and on top I have the text and text fields. The text fields are showing up but not allowing me to add padding as well as there is no title text showing. Please help.[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4J2u.jpg)

Did some more testing to find out that this happens whenever I use a textfield over an image. Not sure if this is a bug or not but it seems to be because as soon as the zstack is removed everything works.

At last ive discovered the issue, the text fields are extending way out of the canvas. Ive fixed the width of the textfield as a temporary solution but still looking for a way to fix this relative to the screen rather than the background as the field extends to the size of the image. Let me know if you can help as im just starting to use xcode!

Comment: Please make sure that you don't share your code as image as this isn't helpful for people that might wanna try it on their machines to help you out! :)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the image cause canvas to be much more bigger and you use edgesIgnoringSafearea(.all)
Try to use on the image clipped() method and i think it will fix your issue with the padding.
And also try to add foregroundColor to the test fields

Comment: I tried clipped and foregroundcolor, has not fixed it. I think it may have something to do with the ZStack cause when i take that out the text fields works. Any thoughts?